# Fetching content from numbered list in file with python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have file with following lines:

**lines.txt**

```
1. robert
   smith
2. harry
3. john
```

I want to get array as follows:

```
["robert\nsmith","harry","john"]
```

I tried something like this:

```
with open('lines.txt') as fh:
    m = [re.match(r"^\d+\.(.*)",line) for line in fh.readlines()]
    print(m)
    for i in m:
        print(i.groups())
```

It outputs following:

```
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='1. robert'>, None, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match='2. harry'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='3. john'>]
(' robert',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspaces\workspace6\PdfGenerator\PdfGenerator.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(i.groups())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

It seems that I am approaching this problem in very wrong way. How you will solve this?

Comment: If you `print (i)` you'll see that `m[1]` is `NoneType` which is why you get the error. To verify that this is the error, try running  `for i in m[2:]:` and you will see how 'groups' work. This doesn't answer your question yet

Answer (score 1):

You may read in the file into memory and use

```
r'(?ms)^\d+\.\s*(.*?)(?=^\d+\.|\Z)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/humIzT/1)

**Details**

- `(?ms)` - enable `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL` modes
- `^` - start of a line
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (this is what `re.findall` returns here): any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=^\d+\.|\Z)` - up to (but not inlcuding) the first occurrence of

  - `^\d+\.` - start of a line, 1+ digits and `.`
  - `|` - or
  - `\Z` - end of string.

Python:

```
with open('lines.txt') as fh:
    print(re.findall(r'(?ms)^\d+\.\s*(.*?)(?=^\d+\.|\Z)', fh.read()))
```

Comment: A more efficient variation is `(?m)^\d+\.\s*(.*(?:\n(?!\d+\.).*)*)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall` to find all from `\d\.\s+` pattern to next '\n\d' pattern or upto end

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+\.\s+(.*?(?=\n\d|$))', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
['robert\n   smith', 'harry', 'john']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split`.

**Regex**: [`\n?\d+\.\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/ZZeVWH/2)

Details:

- `\n` - Newline
- `?` - Matches between zero and one times, match if 'new line' exists
- `\d+` - Matches a digit (+) between one and unlimited times
- `\.` - Dot
- `\s*` - Matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`) (*) between zero and unlimited times

**Python code**:

```
re.split(r'\n?\d+\.\s*', lines)[1:]
```

`[1:]` removes the first item because its empty string

Output:

```
['robert\n   smith', 'harry', 'john']
```

Comment: can you please explain it a bit? Especially `\n?` and `[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution, which gathers **only** names,
without unnecessary spaces in the middle of names,
contrary to some other solutions.

The idea is:

- Save a list of tuples *(number, name_segment)*, "copying"
  the group number from previous line if absent in the current
  line. The pair to be saved is prepared by *getPair* function.
- Group these tuples on the number (first element).
- Join name segments from each group, using *\n* as separator.
- Save these joined names in a result list.

Using list comprehensions allows to write the program in
a quite concise way. See below:

```
import re, itertools

def getPair(line):
  global grp
  nr, nameSegm = re.match(r'^(\d+\.)?\s+(\w+)$', line).groups()
  if nr:  # Number present
    grp = nr
  return grp, nameSegm   

grp = ''    # Group label (number)
with open('lines.txt') as fh:
  lst = [getPair(line) for line in fh.readlines()]
res = ['\n'.join([t[1] for t in g])
  for _, g in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0])]
print(f"Result: {res}")
```

To sum up, the program is a bit longer than other, but is gives
**only** names, without additional spaces.